# java: boolean instanceOf Boolean?

Tags: java, casting, boolean, primitive, autoboxing

I'm a bit confused: I have a function, that takes an Object as argument. But the compiler does not complain if I just pass a primitive and even recognizes a boolean primitive as Boolean Object. Why is that so?

```
public String test(Object value)
{
   if (! (value instanceof Boolean) ) return "invalid";
   if (((Boolean) value).booleanValue() == true ) return "yes";
   if (((Boolean) value).booleanValue() == false ) return "no";
   return "dunno";
}

String result = test(true);  // will result in "yes"
```

Comment: Note a boolean is NEVER an instance of Boolean. You can never pass a primitive to the instanceof operator. Your boolean primitive never entered this method, boxing happened when the invocation happened and method invocation conversion occurred!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because primitive '`true`' will be **[Autoboxed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)** to `Boolean` and which is a `Object`.

Comment: (+1) And here's some [documentation to go along with it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Further reading: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

@jpegzz, the code would not compile if you ran with 1.4.x

Comment: interesting :) Well, the docs suggest only to use autoboxing if really neccessary so I wont. But it's nice to know that this is not a bug but a feature :)

Comment: what is the meaning of ------------    if (object instanceof Boolean ) -----------------then what happends? Means what it things?

Comment: `instanceof` operator checks if the object is instance of Boolean Class

Answer (score 3):

Like previous answers says, it's called autoboxing.

In fact, at compile-time, `javac` will transform your `boolean` primitve value into a `Boolean` object. Notice that typically, reverse transformation may generate very strange `NullPointerException` due, as an example, to the following code

```
Boolean b = null;
if(b==true) <<< Exception here !
```

You can take a look at [JDK documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) for more infos.

Comment: Did you mean `Boolean b = null;`??

Comment: I think you meant `Boolean b = null;` instead of `boolean b = null;`. Note the capital.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the method:

```
  if (((Boolean) value).booleanValue() == true ) return "yes";
  if (((Boolean) value).booleanValue() == false ) return "no";
  return "dunno";
```

Could be replaced with

```
  if (value == null) return "dunno";
  return value ? "yes" : "no";
```

Comment: not the same as OP's code behavior. `null` would return "invalid" since `null` is not an instance of `Boolean` (you're missing that line from OP's code in your first code above); "dunno" would never be returned at all (by original code). Without that line your first code would throw a NPE when value is `null`.

Comment: @Carlos, I can never remember if `instanceof` returns true or false with all nulls, so I usually avoid the case by checking for null beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

its called autoboxing - new with java 1.5

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html