# Need to understand Boxing in core java

Tags: java, object, autoboxing

I cant figure out how the int 7 is consider as object in below example.

The sifer(7) is consider to be method sifer(Object o). I am not able to get it how this happened. In one of my java reference book it says Int can be boxed to an Integer and then "widened" to an object. I am not sure what that means.

```
 >> Class A 
class A { }     

 >> Class B 

class B extends A { }   
 >> Class ComingThru  

public class ComingThru {  
   static String s ="-";    
static void sifer(A[] ...a2)  
{  
    s = s + "1";  
}

static void sifer(B[] b1)  
{
    s += "3";  
}
static void sifer(Object o)   
{
    s += "4";  
}      

   public static void main(String[] args)   {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    A[] aa= new A[2];  
    B[] ba = new B[2];  

    //sifer(aa);  
    //sifer(ba);  
    sifer(7);
    System.out.println(s);  


}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no `sifer(int)` method, the compiler will try to find the "closest match". In this case, the other 2 `sifer` methods take arrays as parameters, which an int clearly isn't.

The last method, `sifer(Object)` can be applied to any objects, including an `Integer` so that's the method that is used for `sifer(7)`.

The [reality is a little more complex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3), and the JVM will look for a matching mathod in the following order:

> - an identity conversion
>
>   - in your case: `sifer(int)` but there is no such method
> - a widening primitive conversion
>
>   - in your case: `sifer(long)` for example, but there is no such method
> - a widening reference conversion
>
>   - in your case: not applicable, int is not an object
> - a boxing conversion optionally followed by widening reference conversion
>
>   - in your case that's what's happening: int is boxed to Integer which is widened to Object
> - an unboxing conversion optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion
>
>   - in your case: not applicable

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Above code provides an classic example of **Method Overloading**, along with **AutoBoxing and Auto-UnBoxing which came by Java 1.5**, cause **manual** Boxing and Unboxing was a pain.

**2.**  `The sifer(A[]... a2)` and `sifer(B[] b1)` both accepts Array type Arguments in its parameter, which no way matches int. So now we are left only with `sifer(Object o)`.

**3.** Now the `int` will be converted into `Wrapper Object Integer` Automatically.

You can verify it by doing this in snifer(Object o) method.

```
    o.getClass().getName();
```

See this link for further details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer.appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`7` will be [auto boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to `Integer` which is an `Object`

**Also See**

- [java: boolean instanceOf Boolean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600686/java-boolean-instanceof-boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Steps as below-

1. The int (7) was boxed to a Integer.
2. The Integer reference was widened to an Object (since Integer extends Object).
3. The sifer() method got an Object reference that actually refers to a Integer
   object.